# Are there equal amounts of energy on each half of the Cosmic Microwave Background image?

Tags: thermodynamics, cosmology, cosmic-microwave-background

And what about if we quartered the image, took it to eights etc.

Comment: Note that the mathematical way to whole, halve, quarter, eighth, ... data on a sphere is via multipole moment (monopole, dipole, quadrupole, octopole,,,); that is, the projections onto $Y_l^m(\theta, \phi)$.

Answer (score 0):

Approximately yes. But there is a famous ["cold spot"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMB_cold_spot) which lowers the average in one part of the sky. This is part of a phenomenon known as the ["axis of evil"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axis_of_evil_(cosmology)) in which the CMB temperature anisotropies are observed to be slightly larger on one half of the sky vs the other.

In general there are several "large scale anamolies" where the low-$\ell$ spectrum of the CMB does not behave quite like you would expect a typical random realization to behave (example review:  Dominik J Schwarz et al 2016 Class. Quantum Grav. 33 184001, https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0264-9381/33/18/184001/ampdf, also see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_microwave_background#Other_anomalies)).

However I think it's fair to say that no one knows if these anomalies are physically significant, or if they are just coincidences, since in any individual realization of a statistical process, if you look hard enough you can always find *apparent* relationships in the data that are just random features of the specific realization you have (["overfitting"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting)).

Comment: The anomaly  that aligns with the ecliptic plane suggests that the sun is somehow affecting the CMBR. If the earth was on a different ecliptic plane or we measured the CMBR from another planet in the solar system  perhaps we would see the same anomaly. Could the CMBR be interacting with the sun's magnetic field or with the solar wind? The cold spot should have corresponding hot spots to make up for the missing energy shouldn't it?

Comment: @AlistairBain No one has been able to explain why the plane of the ecliptic has anything to do with the CMB. But indeed it is suspicious. The cold spot is interesting/unusual because there is an unusually large negative fluctuation. There is not an unusually large positive fluctuation.

Comment: Perhaps the plane of the ecliptic was determined by the sun's magnetic field and solar wind .In this view the Earth is just a large particle that had its orbit set by the sun's magnetic field and/or solar wind over a long period of time.Interaction between earth's magnetism and the sun's may have helped.

Comment: There is no shock wave around the cold spot which a collision of universes would produce. Surely there would be shock waves from particle collisions  or CMB wavelength shifts from gravitational waves.

Comment: @AlistairBain This is a lot of stuff to throw out in the comments and could be the subject of quite a few more questions. The answer to the question you originally asked is, *no,* there are not equal amounts of anisotropy in the northern and southern hemisphere of the CMB, although the difference from equality is small and we don't know if this is important or a coincidence. If you want to propose a specific explanation for these observational facts, that's fine, but should be a separate question.

Comment: Also just be aware that currently *no one* has a compelling explanation of the "axis of evil" in the CMB. If you do have a correct explanation, this would be a major result, but you should perhaps consider how likely it is you will come up with a correct explanation on your own without studying this subject in detail (ie, much more detail than you will get on a Q&A site)

Answer (score 0):

This has been done. The strengths of the ansiotropies in the CMB have been mapped as a function of their *angular scale* (that is, how big they appear in the sky), and the resulting graph contains important information about the dynamics of the big bang at very early times. For example, that chart contains signals which are evidence of an *acoustic rebound* that happened shortly after the big bang occurred. You can think of the acoustic rebound as the universe going BANG!boing-boing-boing (sound effects mine).

Comment: Has somebody calculated the standard errors for 2 divisions, 3 divisions,, 4 divisions etc and do the standard errors follow a pattern? What would a graph of standard error versus number of divisions look like?

Comment: @AlistairBain, yes this has been done, big papers have been written about it, it is exciting stuff indeed.